# Incorrect SSL certification path

Tags: macos, keychain

On our site that we have clients logging into we have a SSL certificate that was issued by GoDaddy.  For some of our MAC users when they connect to our site and you look at the certification path it shows that the SSL certificate was issued by Apple.  It shows this way using either Safari or Chrome.  Is there a way to "clear" this binding and set the issuer as GoDaddy on the users MAC machine?  I have downloaded the GoDaddy Root and Intermediate certificates and loaded them into the Keystore but it did not make a difference.  Odd thing is that it does not affect all MAC users, some login without any issues.  It is a Citrix NetScaler that they are connecting to and I am waiting to hear back from Citrix.

[image: Incorrect Issuer]

Answer (score 0):

Check the Root Certificate you see above named "Apple": It looks like manually added, showing the blue "+"-Sign. I doubt this certificate must be around, delete it and retry (you may save it before deleting it from your keychain, just drag it out and drop it on your Desktop; you may add it later again the same way, if you think it was an error). To delete it, open Keychain Access, search it, mark it and press the "backspace" key.

I can see the following "Apple" Root Certificates on my machines:

- Apple Root CA
- Apple Root CA - G2
- Apple Root CA - G3
- Apple Root Certificate Authority

Comment: I removed the Apple cert from Keychain Access, cleared cached items in Safari, reconnect to the site and it shows the GoDaddy cert.  When the user reboots the machine, the Apple certificate is back in Keychain Access and when we connect to the site it shows Apple as the Issuer.  The Plus Sign next to the Apple certificate means that the certificate is set to "Always Trust"  I tried Locking the System Keychain Access to see if that would prevent the Apple key from being added but the System Keychain icon keeps showing as unlocked.